# How to full delete in Sonata Admin (one to many relation)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Iam using Sonata Admin. Have a `House` and `Room` entitys with one to many relation. Iam use the `CollectionType` field for relation.

If i check `delete`, when edit a list of rooms and press `Save` - it set null relation field `house_id` in `room` table, but record still not delete.

How to fix this? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give to Relation field

```
Cascade ={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true
```